# 1 Powershell Script 2 SQL Tables

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, powershell

I am having trouble populating my second table in my SQL Server Management Studio. 
My first table `ServerList` contains all information in the screenshot below. The second table `ServerDrives` should then contain all the information regarding hard drive specs (free, used, letter, and which server are the hard drives connected to).

Currently, I have my powershell script pull from the `ServerList` all the values in the column `ServerName` and push info into the powershell script which will then populate OS, RAM, and etc.

**Issue: I am not sure how to have the same powershell script use the same primary key `ServerID` from table `ServerList` to populate my `ServerDrives` table. For I want each row in that table to be one for each server in `ServerList`. I have in the script currently a way to collect the hard drive information but I am not sure how to use that info to populate my empty table**

---

**Goal:** To have ServerID (primary key in `ServerList`) and ServerDriveID (primary key in `ServerDrives`) be for the same server (QAGGAPP01, QAGGAPP03, QAGGAPP05, and etc). To have the variable `$disks` be pushed in the database table `ServerDrives` with the proper hard drives letters and specs. Each server has 1 or 2 hard drives.

**Code:**

```
    Write-Output " `n Start of Hal0 `n";

    #Start of Server Connection
    $connectionString = "Server=QAUTILITYDB01;Database=Hal0Test;Integrated Security=True;"
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
    $connection.Open()
    $command = $connection.CreateCommand()

    $ServerArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $query = "SELECT ServerName FROM ServerList"
    $command.CommandText = $query
    $ServerNames = $command.ExecuteReader()

    $table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
    $table.Load($ServerNames)

    $ServerArray = $table | select -Expand ServerName

    $ServerArray | ForEach-Object {
        #$ServerArray returns each server name

        #Operating System
        $SystemInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername  $_
        $os = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $_ 
        #Server's Memory (RAM) Usage Average
        $TotalRAM = [math]::round($SystemInfo.TotalVisibleMemorySize/1MB,4)
        $FreeRAM =  [math]::round($SystemInfo.FreePhysicalMemory/1MB,3)
        $UsedRAM = $TotalRAM - $FreeRAM
        $RAMPercentFree = [math]::round(($FreeRAM / $TotalRAM) * 100,3)
        $RAMPercentUsed = [math]::round(($UsedRAM / $TotalRAM) * 100,3)
        #Server's CPU (Proccess) Usage Average
        $cpuAVG = Get-WmiObject -computername $_ win32_processor |     Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average 

        #Server's Hard Drives (MB) Free/Used
        $disks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Computer $_ |
             Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} |
             ForEach-Object {
                 '{0} {1:D} MB Free/{2:D} MB Used' -f $_.DeviceID,
                     [int]($_.FreeSpace/1MB), [int]($_.Size/1MB)
             }

        #Value Types being pushed to Server
        $command.CommandText = "UPDATE ServerList SET FQDN = '$_',
        TotalRAM= '$TotalRAM' ,
        FreeRAM= '$FreeRAM' ,
        UsedRAM= '$UsedRAM' ,
        RAMPercentFree = '$RAMPercentFree' ,
        RAMPercentUsed= '$RAMPercentUsed' ,
        OS = '$($os.Caption)' WHERE ServerName LIKE '$($os.PSComputerName)%';"
        $result = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
}

    Write-Output "`n End of Hal0";
```

---

**ServerDrives:**

[image]

---

HTML Preview, I only have in my powershell code just to make it easier to see what is being pushed to the server without having to reopen the tables everytime:

[image]

Comment: Your second, unfinished, SQL script is an UPDATE but you are saying the `ServerDrives` table is empty. There's nothing to update then – instead, you want to INSERT data into it. On the other hand, if your PS script is supposed to be run more than once, you would need to either clear that table each time before repopulating it or merge the new info with the contents of `ServerDrives`, i.e. some of its rows would be updated, others inserted, while still others even deleted (if that is a possibility). If you clean up the table every time, `ServerDriverID` values will be generated every time anew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on suggestion in another comment to get **ServerID**. You can change your code as follows:

- Get both name and id using **"SELECT ServerID, ServerName FROM ServerList"**
- Pipe resulting table and read **$ServerName** and **$ServerID** separately
- Use this information when you iterate over your disks to insert/update **$ServerID**

### Implementation:

```
#Start of Server Connection
$ConnectionString = "<CONNECTION>"
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$Connection.Open()
$Command = $Connection.CreateCommand()
# Selects server id and name and puts it into the table
$ServerInfoQuery = "SELECT ServerID, ServerName FROM ServerList"
$Command.CommandText = $ServerInfoQuery
$ServerInfoReader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
$ServerInfo = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$ServerInfo.Load($ServerInfoReader)    
$ServerInfo | ForEach-Object {
    # Read Name and ID from table
    $ServerName = $_.ServerName
    $ServerID = $_.ServerID
    # Operating System
    $SystemInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername  $ServerName
    $os = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $ServerName        
    $TotalRAM = [math]::round($SystemInfo.TotalVisibleMemorySize/1MB,4)
    $FreeRAM =  [math]::round($SystemInfo.FreePhysicalMemory/1MB,3)
    $UsedRAM = $TotalRAM - $FreeRAM
    $RAMPercentFree = [math]::round(($FreeRAM / $TotalRAM) * 100,3)
    $RAMPercentUsed = [math]::round(($UsedRAM / $TotalRAM) * 100,3)
    # Server's CPU (Proccess) Usage Average
    $cpuAVG = Get-WmiObject -computername $ServerName win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average         
    # Value Types being pushed to Server
    $Command.CommandText = "
        UPDATE 
            ServerList 
        SET 
            FQDN = '$ServerName',
            TotalRAM= '$TotalRAM',
            FreeRAM= '$FreeRAM',
            UsedRAM= '$UsedRAM',
            RAMPercentFree = '$RAMPercentFree',
            RAMPercentUsed= '$RAMPercentUsed',
            OS = '$($os.Caption)' 
        WHERE 
            ServerID = $ServerID"       
    $result = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    # Server's Hard Drives (MB) Free/Used
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Computer $ServerName | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} | ForEach-Object {
        $DriveLetter = $_.DeviceID
        $DiskFree = [Math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1MB, 0)        
        $DiskUsed = [Math]::Round($_.Size/1MB, 0)
        $Command.CommandText = "
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ServerDrives WHERE ServerID = '$ServerID' AND DriveLetter = '$DriveLetter')
            BEGIN
                UPDATE
                    ServerDrives
                SET
                    DriveLetter = '$DriveLetter',
                    DiskFree = '$DiskFree',
                    DiskUsed = '$DiskUsed',
                    ServerID = '$ServerID'
                WHERE
                    ServerID = '$ServerID' AND DriveLetter = '$DriveLetter' 
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO 
                    ServerDrives (DriveLetter, DiskFree, DiskUsed, ServerID) 
                VALUES 
                    ('$DriveLetter','$DiskFree','$DiskUsed', '$ServerID')
            END"
        $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great stuff, let me try it out! Thank you Petr!

Comment: I am so sorry I just gave the wrong person the bounty... The above solution.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just fetch the primary key when you ask for the server names?

```
$query = "SELECT ServerID, ServerName FROM ServerList"
```

Now you can use `WHERE ServerID = $CurrentServerID` or somesuch.

You're not running any INSERT statements.  It's a SELECT followed by UPDATE.  If you need the primary key, just ask the server for it.

Comment: Not as simple as that. The name list goes into `$ServerNames`, which is then expanded into an FQDN list stored in `$ServerArray`. It is `$ServerArray` that is iterated over, not `$ServerNames`. So likely other changes will be needed too. But I agree, it would seem easiest to get both IDs and names at the beginning: names for getting the information, IDs for referencing the tables' rows.

Comment: @AndriyM I'm not saying the changes are simple, just that the solution is pretty simple.  Don't iterate over `$ServerArray`.  Iterate over each record in the DataTable.  Something like `foreach ($row in $table) {....}`.  Then you have `$row.ServerId` and `$row.ServerName`.

Comment: Yes, I just thought it was worth pointing out in the answer, because the OP cannot *just* fetch the primary key – they need to restructure the script a little as well.

Comment: Thank you guys for the feedback but the thought process is not my issue. I just need a push (start code) of how to accomplish this goal. Even if the push is the code for pushing the value of free space on C Drive to the database. I can figure out the rest like what I did for the first table. Coded answers would help GREATLY! Thank you already for the current reponses!